# Privacy Policy, ToS Pages with Meta KW and Desc?

Tags: seo, web-crawler

I am currently in the process of making my website SEO, and I was wondering if I should have a meta keyword and description for the Terms of Service and Privacy Police page.

Currently I only have a meta description for these 2 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a meta description is always a good idea as, if well crafted, search engines may use that in the search result snippets. If you don't specify one, search engines will just use some other text from the page. Generally it's a good idea to specify a meta description because then you have better control over what's shown in the search results for your pages, but it's definitely not the end of the world if you omit it.

As for meta keywords, to my knowledge no search engine uses it thus it's not worth spending time on it.